# "can't convert string into integer" error in crypt/blowfish in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, blowfish, crypt

Migrating an application from rails2 to rails3 and i am facing an error `can't convert String into Integer` in crypt/blowfish.

config/core_ext/string.rb file:

```
def encrypt(key) <br/>
  blowfish = Crypt::Blowfish.new(key)
  blowfish.encrypt_string(self)
end
```

The method called from test/unit/core_ext/string_test.rb

```
def test_encryption
  key = "test"
  encrypted = str.encrypt(key)
end
```

How to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there are problems with Blowfish in Ruby 1.9+. You can [update the blowfish gem](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/203985) or use [gist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218216/blowfish-encrypted-url-in-ruby).